# What is wrong with this mysql inner join code?

Tags: mysql

I created this code but it seems not to be working. is it right to a in the where clause paymentnotification.subpayment and collections.status

```
    $sql = "SELECT collections.categoryid,collections.handler,collections.status,paymentnotification.categoryid,paymentnotification.amount,paymentnotification.payee,paymentnotification.paymentdate 
FROM collections
INNER JOIN paymentnotification
ON paymentnotification.month=collections.month AND paymentnotification.categoryid=collections.categoryid
 WHERE paymentnotification.subpayment=? AND  collections.status=? AND collections.year=? BETWEEN ? AND ?";
$p = $conn->prepare($sql);
$p->execute(array($payment,$status,$year,$monthc,$monthc2));
```

Comment: Define "seem not to be working".

Comment: What is the error message? I would use brakets around your join causes

Comment: @sdespont, please can you explain what you meant about the bracket.

Comment: I mean `INNER JOIN paymentnotification ON (paymentnotification.month=collections.month AND paymentnotification.categoryid=collections.categoryid)`

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that this:

```
AND collections.year=? BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

is apparently supposed to be this:

```
AND collections.year=? AND collections.month BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

(Incidentally, I recommend using shorter lines, with well-placed line-breaks. When you have to scroll horizontally to read each line, it becomes very hard to follow.)

Comment: how do I then make the search for the year. I have edited the original question.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah: I've edited my answer accordingly.